# Why do I get a ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, linked-list, priority-queue

Why do I get a ConcurrentModificationException at the specified location in my code? I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong... The `removeMin()` method is being used to locate the min in the list `pq`, remove it, and return its value

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class test1 {

    static LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        list.add(10);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(12);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(7);

        System.out.println(removeMin());
    }

    public static Integer removeMin() {
        LinkedList<Integer> pq = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        Iterator<Integer> itPQ = pq.iterator();

        // Put contents of list into pq
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            pq.add(list.removeFirst());
        }

        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int pos = 0;
        int remPos = 0;

        while (itPQ.hasNext()) {
            Integer element = itPQ.next(); // I get ConcurrentModificationException here
            if (element < min) {
                min = element;
                remPos = pos;
            }
            pos++;
        }

        pq.remove(remPos);
        return remPos;
    }

}
```

Comment: My guess would be that since you create the `Iterator` *before* you start adding extra elements the iterator suddenly has it's data updated under it's feet, so to speak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Iterator should not be considered usable once the Collection from which it was obtained is modified.  (This restriction is relaxed for java.util.concurrent.* collection classes.)

You are first obtaining an Iterator for `pq`, then modifying `pq`.  Once you modify `pq`, the Iterator `itPQ` is no longer valid, so when you try to use it, you get a ConcurrentModificationException.

One solution is to move `Iterator<Integer> itPQ = pq.iterator();` to right before the `while` loop.  A better approach is to do away with the explicit use of Iterator altogether:

```
for (Integer element : pq) {
```

Technically, the for-each loop uses an Iterator internally, so either way, this loop would only be valid as long as you don’t try to modify `pq` inside the loop.

Comment: upvoted for the foreach approach. Personally I think this is much cleaner

Comment: @VGR "You are first obtaining an Iterator for pq, then modifying pq". This in itself is not the issue. The issue is that the iterator's own add method was not used. to add the elements to `pq`. If you use the add method provided by ListIterator, the iterator can traverse `pq` without problems. But I like the solution.

Comment: I agree with the above statement and I have modified my code, but now when I remove the minimum value it comes up with an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @kprog Sounds like a different issue which should be asked as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You face an issue because you added items to `pq`, using the normal `.add()` method after you had already created an Iterator for `pq`. The Iterator doesn't complain when you do the `hasNext()` because it sees the change in `pq`.

```
while (itPQ.hasNext()) {
    ...
    Integer element = itPQ.next(); --> you get exception here
    ...
```

}

However, it throws an exception when you attempt to iterate through `pq`. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965484/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-with-iterator),  *"If the iterator detects that some modifications were made without using its method (or using another iterator on the same collection), it cannot guarantee anymore that it will not pass twice on the same element or skip one, so it throws this exception."*

Comment: While I agree that this is definitely sketchy code, OP specifically states that the error is not thrown here

Comment: This has nothing to do with `list`.  The exception is due to obtaining `itPQ`, then modifying `pq`, then trying to use `itPQ`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and it turns out that the offending line is here:

```
Iterator<Integer> itPQ = pq.iterator();
```

This needs to come *after* your population of `pq`, so that the iterator does not have it's data updated asynchronously.

With this modification the code runs.

---

Now, it does **not** run correctly. The reason is as @Ishnark pointed out in his answer, that every time you are removing from the list, it gets smaller, and so not all of the list is being added to `pq`.