# Java - Filter a list based on multiple values

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to filter out a list based on values. I have two `List`. One is a list of names which i want to remove i.e present in `animalList`. And another is the main primary list `AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList` from where i have to remove the object which matches the names from `animalList`. Now i do have the solution but i think it takes lot of time. Below is the code. I am using Java 8. Can it be optimised?

```
if(animalList!=null && animalList.size()>0)
        {
            for(AnimalFilterPojo dtoObject:animalList)
            {
                if(!dtoObject.getApproved())
                {
                    for(AnimalPrimaryDataPojo mainDtoObject: AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList)
                    {
                        if(mainDtoObject.getAnimalName().equalsIgnoreCase(dtoObject.getValue()))
                        {   
                            AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList.remove(mainDtoObject);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you want to remove elements from a list while iterating on it, you will have to manually instantiate the `iterator` and use `iterator.remove()` or you will have [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965484/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-with-iterator/16965558).
A better solution is to use `stream()`, `filter()` and `collect(Collectors.toList())`.

Comment: Optimized for what? Speed? Amount of braces? This piece of code is probably an indication of a larger design problem, so even if you convert this to use streams it won't really help. Your naming is also quite clumsy, adding `Pojo` to the end of a class name, especially when you then use `dtoObject` as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

Use `removeAll()` method.

```
AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList.removeAll(animalList);
```

It will remove the objects of `animalList` from `AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList`

N.B: You need to implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` method in `AnimalFilterPojo`

Comment: Cannot use. Both list are different. AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList has one of the property  of animalList

Comment: @sTg Then how are you writing `AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList.remove(dtoObject);` ?? it should be `AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList.remove(mainDtoObject);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 streams to filter the list. In below example Parent is the object which has `abc` property of type String. We are filtering `List<Parent> objs` using `List<String> names`

```
public class ListFilterDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Parent> objs = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Parent> filtersObjs = objs.parallelStream().filter((obj) -> names.contains(obj.getAbc())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

class Parent {
    private String abc;

    public Parent(String abc) {
        this.abc = abc;
    }

    public String getAbc() {
        return this.abc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
if(animalList!=null && animalList.size()>0)
    animalList.removeIf(animal ->
        AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList.stream()
           .filter(filter -> !filter.getApproved())
           .map(AnimalFilter::getValue)
           .collect(Collectors.toList()).contains(animal.getAnimalName()));
```

to explain the code: here we use `removeIf()` on the List to remove the objects using a `Predicate` that is a lambda that receives the `animal` and filters the list by removing the elements by name where name is taken from a list generated as a selection of the `AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList` of the elments that have the approved flag (the second `filter`), extracting the `value` (using the `map`) and constructing a list out of it using a `Collector`.

The portion:

```
AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList.stream()
   .filter(filter -> !filter.getApproved())
   .map(AnimalFilter::getValue)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

generates the list to be used as a filter

```
animalList.removeIf(animal ->
    <generated list>.contains(animal.getAnimalName()));
```

uses list generated in place to apply the filter.
Beware that this of course modifies the list you have
Besides, you should not start a variable with a capital letter like you did for AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [**`removeIf`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) then use `AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList` as the source in which case you'll need to invert your logic within the `if` block i.e:

```
if(animalList != null && animalList.size() > 0){
      AnimalPrimaryDataPojoFilterList.removeIf(x -> 
                    animalList.parallelStream()
                   .filter(e -> !e.getApproved() && x.getAnimalName().equalsIgnoreCase(e.getValue())).findAny().orElse(null) != null);
}
```